# Url changes event React ^6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

### Background to the Question

When creating one page layouts it is common to have a navigation with "#anchor" links. Clicking on such link, the page scrolls down to the matching section with id of "anchor".

In next.js there is a function called `useRouter()` that can detect url changed like the following:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const handleRouteChange = () => {
    window.history.replaceState(null, '', '/');
  };

  router.events.on('hashChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);

  // If the component is unmounted, unsubscribe
  // from the event with the `off` method:
  return () => {
    router.events.off('hashChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
  };
}, []);
```

### The question

In React 6 and above, how do you check if the url changes. OnClick function is not an option.

### What I have tried

Using regular javascript event listeners:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const handleRouteChange = () => {
    window.history.replaceState(null, '', '/');
  };

  window.addEventListener('locationchange', handleRouteChange);

  // If the component is unmounted, unsubscribe
  // from the event with the `off` method:
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('locationchange', handleRouteChange);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: React 6 isn't a thing, do you mean `react-router-dom` v6? You can use the `useLocation` hook and pass `location` as a dependency to an `useEffect` hook and issue any side-effects for when the current location changes.

Comment: Yeah, wrong by me... react-router-dom v6 of course.  I have tried with useLocation without any result. I tried once again and now got it to work.... Fell so dumb, thanks!